# What is a WPF Library (.NET Core) project target

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I own the source code to a class library of "utilities" which I targeted to .NET Framework 4.8.  I want to port it to use in a .NET Core desktop client app and port it to use in a .NET Core web service.

I know that new `.NET Core` projects have a new kind of project file that is described as SDK-style. It seems possible to verify VS is working with the new style because the first line of the project file mentions the word "sdk" and Visual Studio's right click on a project allows editing of the project file. The  [try-convert conversion tool](https://github.com/dotnet/try-convert) is described as being incomplete and unsupported so I am pasting source code files into projects.

When I paste my source code into a `Class Library (.NET Core)` project it fails to compile for missing assemblies. There seems to be no way to add a reference to a Microsoft class like System.Windows.Documents.FlowDocument which is in `PresentationFramework.dll`. I can only add a COM Reference (not what I want) or Project Reference (in other words "home-made", not Microsoft, not what I want).

When I paste my source code into a `WPF Library (.NET Core)` project it compiles. This library has no WPF features because it is full of utility classes and utility methods so this project type seems a strange choice.  I only guessed it might work because this [tutorial](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/porting-desktop-apps-to-net-core/) mentions manually editing project files for WPF apps and Windows Forms apps.  It does not tell you anything about any alternatives that are not apps. In other words, the tutorial does not mention libraries.

EDIT: The following question was edited to be "less broad" than the original.

Why does a `WPF Library (.NET Core)` succeed where  `Class Library (.NET Core)` fails ?

Details: Visual Studio 2019 Community

RESOLUTION:  "Class Library" worked when targeting .NET Framework 4.8 but now the choice must be "WPF Library" when targeting .NET Core. As @DavidAWhite says, FlowDocument is part of WPF.

Comment: With some tweaks, a lot of ports can work, however if you are using depreciated 3rd party libraries or otherwise, then this can become a problem, however even then with some tweaks its possible to get them to work "sometimes". However, this question is too broad

Comment: @TheGeneral , It's not deprecated nor 3rd party. If I want to make a .DLL the natural choice is "Class Library" so this deserves an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .NET Core Class Library doesn't have any references to WPF or anything like that. That would be way too much and not be portable.  Unlike a .NET Standard class library, you can reference things like WPF, ASP.NET Core 3.x, Winforms or other parts of .NET Standard 2.x that are not part of any .NET Framework or Mono implementation.

You can make a .NET Core Class Library reference WPF by using `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">` and `<UseWpf>true</UseWpf>` in your csproj file.

Whether you like it or not `System.Windows.Documents.FlowDocument` *is* part of WPF and this is the way you now reference all framework provided WPF components.

Comment: I don't want to reference WPF. This is a set of general purpose utilities.

Comment: @H2ONaCl fair enough. its up to you what you want to target.

Comment: It doesn't work when I use "Class Library".

Comment: @H2ONaCl what doesn't work? `System.Windows.Documents.FlowDocument` is part of WPF, whether you like it or not

Comment: Of course there is also the concern about what side effects are caused by the work-around of selecting WPF Library as the project type.

Comment: @H2ONaCl i'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I infer you're saying this is not a workaround.